# Проверка существования триггера MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Делаю такой запрос**

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_todo AFTER DELETE ON user_todo_send FOR EACH ROW BEGIN....
```

**Пишет ошибку**:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `IF NOT EXISTS update_todo`

Не пойму где я допустил ошибку

Comment: Кажется, что MySQL не поддерживает `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @PeterOlson  Да Вы правы не поддерживает, но как реализовать проверку?  я используюю Yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), *mysql* не поддерживает условную конструкцию `if not exists` в команде `create trigger`.

если триггер уже существует, то команда `create trigger` завершится ошибкой.

если такое поведение нежелательно, можно на более высоком уровне (т.е., в программе, обращающейся к *mysql-серверу*) предварительно проверять существование триггера перед выполнением команды создания. например, с помощью команды [`show triggers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-triggers.html).

Comment: А как мне это реализовать на php. Мне нужно проверить существование триггера. Когда я делаю команду `Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE user_todo_send")->query()`  то получаю ошибку, использую Yii

Comment: @modelfak, создайте, пожалуйста, новый **вопрос** по этому поводу.